# Drupal 7 - How to access subsite on dev environment

Tags: dns, drupal-7

I am working on a drupal site using Domain Module 
https://www.drupal.org/project/domain

There was a test copy of the site in a sandbox. The subdomain on the live site have real domain names, but i can't work there. How do i access the front end (not the admin) of these sites on the sandbox copy of the site?

So far i have tried:

```
test.mysite.com/domain/view/4
test.mysite.com/domain/4 
test.mysite.com/d
```

omain/content/4

but none of these work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a module called Domain Alias part of the Domain package you are using. When enabled, you will see a tab "Aliases" when you edit each domain in your site, for example /admin/structure/domain/view/1/alias would be the path to the Alias settings of your first domain.

You need to add "test.mysite.com" as alias to your domain "www.mysite.com" with the option "Do not redirect". That will make this domain accessible under both domain names. You should add aliases to all domains you need to access under different names.

You can have many aliases for the same domain if you have multiple environments. Having multiple aliases in the production database usually does no harm, you don't need to keep them as local values in the test site.

Comment: Thanks. I just change the domain itself, while i was waiting for reply and that worked for me. But thanks for letting me know about the alias, i just tried it and worked too. Thanks again,